# How to check if the elements in the main diagonal of a square matrix are the same?

Tags: c, arrays, matrix, multidimensional-array

I have to write a program which checks whether the elements (numbers) in the main diagonal of a square matrix (n x n) are the same (return 1 if they are, return 0 if they are not) using a function which is called by `main()`. The matrix is read from a file, done in `main()`.

Here is my function so far: (The function `checkdiag()` does not seem to be working, only the `main()` function is printing out data)

```
#include <stdio.h>
int checkdiag(int matrix[][100], int size)
{
    int i,j;
    for (i=0; i<size; i++)
    {
        for (j=0; j<size; j++)
        {
            if (matrix[i][100]==matrix[j][100])
            {
                return (1);
                printf ("\nThe elements in the main diagonal of the matrix are the same.\n");
            }
            else
            {
                return (0);
                printf ("\nThe elements in the main diagonal are not the same.\n");
            }
        }
    }
}
int main (void)
{
    int matrix[100][100];
    int size, diag;
    int i,j;
    FILE *data;
    data= fopen("data10.txt", "r");`

    fscanf (data, "%d", &size);
    printf ("The size of the matrix is %dx%d, and the matrix is:\n", size, size);
    for (i=0; i<size; i++)
    {
        for (j=0; j<size; j++)
        {
            fscanf (data, "%d", &matrix[i][j]);
            printf (" %d% ", matrix[i][j]);
        }
        printf ("\n");
    }
    diag= checkdiag(matrix, size);
}
```

If someone could please help me see where I am going wrong, I would appreciate it!

P.S The file I'm using is:

```
3
4 5 6
7 8 9
3 6 7
```

Where the first value in the file (3) is the size of the matrix. (i.e 3x3)

Comment: The return(1) should only occur after it completes the loop.  ALL entries must match for it to be the same but only one mismatch indicate the diagonal is not all of one value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void){

FILE *file = fopen("data.txt","r");
int size, i, j;

fscanf(file, "%d" , &size);
int matrix[size][size];

// Read the data into the matrix
for(i=0; i<size; i++){
    for(j=0; j<size; j++){
        fscanf(file, " %d", &matrix[i][j] );
    }
}

//determine if all diagonal entries in the matrix match the one at matrix[0][0]
i=matrix[0][0];
j=0;
while(j < size ){
    if(matrix[j][j] != i)
        break;
    else{
        j++;
    }
}

//if j is equal to the size of the matrix then voila! diagonal entries match.
if(j==size){
    printf("The diagonal is the same\n");
    return 1;
}else{
    printf("The diagonal is not the same\n");
    return 0;
}
}
```

This returns: The diagonal is not the same. For the input:

```
5
1 2 3 4 5
2 1 4 5 6
2 3 1 5 6
2 3 4 1 6
2 3 4 4 2
```

This returns: The diagonal is the same. For the input:

```
5
1 2 3 4 5
2 1 4 5 6
2 3 1 5 6
2 3 4 1 6
2 3 4 4 1
```

Comment: Note: this takes a variable sized matrix. you don't have to set the size to 100 like you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

Your `printf` statements are after your return statements, so they'll never execute. A higher compiler warning level should warn you of code that cannot be reached. Also, you are using the value `100` where you mean to use the variable `j`.

However, you will find that your algorithm is incorrect in any case. It stops comparing after the first comparison. You need to check all diagonal elements.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this `checkdiag()`:

```
int checkdiag(int matrix[][100], int size)
{
    int i;
    for (i=1; i<size; i++)
    {
        if (matrix[i][i] != matrix[0][0])
        {
            printf ("\nThe elements in the main diagonal are not the same.\n");
            return 0;
        }
    }
    printf ("\nThe elements in the main diagonal of the matrix are the same.\n");
    return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

- As this function can only ever process square matrices, and you pass the size, maybe you should use it properly in the prototype: `int checkdiag(int matrix[size][size], int size)`
- The elements in the main diagonal have the same column index and row index, thus you only need one loop.
- You can return the moment you find the first element on the main-diagonal not the same as the element at [0][0], but you cannot conclude success if the first comparison is true. You must compare all elements.
- No statement after a `return` statement is ever executed, unless there are control statements avoiding the `return`.
- `" %d% "` is a bad format string for `printf`. You need to escape a literal `%` in a format string with a second `%`-character, like this: `%%`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `cout<<;` statements return 1 or 0 accordingly.

```
 #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;

    int main(int arc, char *argv[]) {
        int array[100][100];
        int size;
        cout << "Enter size\n";
        cin >> size;
        cout << "Enter matrix\n";
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
                cin >> array[i][j];
            }
        }

        for (int i = 1; i < size; i++) {
            if (array[i][i] != array[i-1][i-1]) {
                cout << "Not Same ";
                break;      
            } else if (i == (size - 1)) {
                cout << "Same";
            } else {
                continue;
            }
        }



    }
```

Comment: Squished code like that is ugly, harder to read, and is frowned upon in most code shops where there are coding standards/formatting rules for integration into the gate.  Just because you *can* format code quickly/sloppily and avoid all syntax considerations doesn't mean you should. Google 'coding standards', and 'code formatting' and try to cultivate a better discipline for your code that improves its maintainability, not just for you but for others. If everyone applies their own idiosyncratic idea then it's a zoo. Better to have some sort of workable consistent standard.

Comment: I edited the answer and added spaces, and as you can see it looks much better, and easier to see each argument instead of everything crammed together in a rush and no separation